# Sports league creation script

Tags: python, console

I'm building a little game that lets you generate a random sports league with random teams and random rosters. What are some ways that I can improve the readability and performance for this code?

### Main Code

```py
import csv
import os
import random

import utilities.resources as resources
import utilities.saves as saves

from src.objects.league import League
from src.objects.team import Team
from src.objects.player import Player

league_config = {}

def verify_league_config():
    try:
        if int(league_config['league-player-count']) < (
            min_player_count := int(league_config['roster-size']) * int(league_config['team-count'])):
                print(f'For the league-player-count, please use a number greater than or equal to {min_player_count}')
                return False
    except KeyError:
        print('Check if each of the required fields exist then try again')
    except IndexError:
        print('Check if the config file is properly formatted then try again')
        return False

    return True

def generate_teams(league):
    team_count = int(league_config['team-count'])
    with open(os.path.join(
            resources.get_resources(), './team_generator_food.csv'), 'r') as file:
        all_teams = [t for t in file.read().splitlines()]

        for i in range(0, team_count):
            picked_team_index = random.randint(0, team_count-i)
            league.add_team(Team(all_teams.pop(picked_team_index)))

def generate_players(league):
    league_player_count = int(league_config['league-player-count'])

    csv_contents = list(csv.reader(open(os.path.join(resources.get_resources(), './player_generator_food.csv'), 'r')))

    first_names = [r[0] for r in csv_contents]
    last_names = [r[1] for r in csv_contents]

    for i in range(0, league_player_count):
        fn_index = random.randint(1, len(csv_contents)-1)
        tmp = fn_index
        ln_index = random.randint(1, len(csv_contents)-1)
        tmp = ln_index
        position = 'OFF' if random.randint(0, 2) % 2 == 0 else 'DEF'
        rating = random.triangular(0, 100, 50) // 1

        league.add_player(Player(first_names[fn_index], last_names[ln_index], position, rating))

def extract_league_config():
    with open(os.path.join(resources.get_configs(), './league_config.yaml'), 'r') as file:
        for line in file.read().splitlines():
            key = line.split(':')[0]
            value = line.split(':')[1].strip()
            league_config[key] = value

def build_configuration():
    while True:
        team_count = input(
            'How many teams would you like to start off with?\n$ ')

        if not team_count.isdigit():
            print('Please insert a number')

        else:
            league_config['team-count'] = int(team_count)
            break

    while True:
        roster_size = input('How many players do you want on each roster?\n$ ')

        if not roster_size.isdigit():
            print('Please insert a number')

        else:
            league_config['roster-size'] = int(roster_size)
            break

    while True:
        league_player_count = input('How many players do you want in the league?\n$ ')

        if not roster_size.isdigit():
            print('Please insert a number')

        if int(league_player_count) < (min_player_count := league_config['roster-size'] * league_config['team-count']):
            print(f'Please use a number greater than or equal to {min_player_count}')

        else:
            league_config['league-player-count'] = int(league_player_count)
            break

    league_config['player-retirement-percentage'] = 10
    league_config['player-retirement-percentage-margin-of-error'] = 5

def execute():
    league = League()

    while True:
        has_config_file = input(
            'Do you have a configuration file that you would like to use which is inserted in the resources folder and named league-config.json?\ny for Yes\nn for No\n$ ')

        if has_config_file != 'y' and has_config_file != 'n':
            print('You must specify Y for Yes or N for No.\n')
            continue

        if has_config_file == 'y':
            extract_league_config()
            if not verify_league_config():
                continue
            break

        if has_config_file == 'n':
            build_configuration()
            break

    # Generate Team
    generate_teams(league)

    # Generate Players
    generate_players(league)

    # Create temp save
    saves.create_temp_save(league.get_json())

    print('League created successfully')
    return league
```

### Dependencies:

#### utils/resources.py

```py
import os


def get_resources():
    """Returns absolute path to resources/ directory"""
    absolute_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    relative_path = '../../resources'
    full_path = os.path.join(absolute_path, relative_path)

    return full_path


def get_configs():
    """Returns absolute path to configs/ directory"""
    absolute_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    relative_path = '../../config'
    full_path = os.path.join(absolute_path, relative_path)

    return full_path


def get_saves():
    """Returns absolute path to saves/ directory"""
    absolute_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    relative_path = '../../saves'
    full_path = os.path.join(absolute_path, relative_path)

    return full_path
```

#### utils/saves.py:

```py
import json
import os
import uuid

from .resources import get_saves

def create_temp_save(data):
    with open(os.path.join(get_saves(), f'tmp_{uuid.uuid4()}'), 'w') as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

#### objects/league.py

```py
import json

from .player import Player
from .team import Team

class League:
    def __init__(self):
        self.teams = []
        self.players = []
        self.free_agents = []

    def add_team(self, team):
        self.teams.append(team)

    def remove_team(self, team):
        self.teams.remove(team)

    #################################################

    def add_player(self, player):
        self.players.append(player)
        self.free_agents.append(player)

    def print_players(self, filters={}):
        row_widths = [10, 9, 4]
        f_pad = ''
        l_pad = ''
        t_pad = ''

        filtered_players = self.players

        if 'fn' in filters:
            filtered_players = [p for p in filtered_players if p.first_name.startswith(filters['fn'])]
        if 'ln' in filters:
            filtered_players = [p for p in filtered_players if p.last_name.startswith(filters['ln'])]
        if 'p' in filters:
            filtered_players = [p for p in filtered_players if p.position.startswith(filters['p'])]
        if 'r' in filters:
            filtered_players = [p for p in filtered_players if p.rating == filters['r']]
        if 't' in filters:
            filtered_players = [p for p in filtered_players if p.team.startswith(filters['t'])]

        for player in filtered_players:
            if len(player.first_name) > row_widths[0]:
                f_pad += f_pad.ljust(len(player.first_name) - row_widths[0], ' ')
                row_widths[0] = len(player.first_name)

            if len(player.last_name) > row_widths[1]:
                l_pad += l_pad.ljust(len(player.last_name) - row_widths[1], ' ')
                row_widths[1] = len(player.last_name)

            if len(player.get_team()) > row_widths[2]:
                t_pad += t_pad.ljust(len(player.get_team()) - row_widths[2], ' ')
                row_widths[2] = len(player.get_team())

        player_table = f'First Name{f_pad} | Last Name{l_pad} | Team{t_pad} | Position | Rating\n'

        for i in range(0, len(filtered_players)):
            t_fn = (f'{filtered_players[i].first_name}').ljust(row_widths[0], ' ')
            t_ln = (f'{filtered_players[i].last_name}').ljust(row_widths[1], ' ')
            t_t = (f'{filtered_players[i].get_team()}').ljust(row_widths[2], ' ')
            t_p = (f'{filtered_players[i].position}').ljust(8, ' ')
            t_r = filtered_players[i].rating

            player_table += f'{t_fn} | {t_ln} | {t_t} | {t_p} | {t_r}\n'

        print(player_table)

    def remove_player(self, player):
        self.players.remove(player)
        self.free_agents.remove(player)

    #################################################

    def get_json(self):
        data = {}

        data['teams'] = [team.get_json() for team in self.teams]
        data['free_agents'] = [free_agent.get_json() for free_agent in self.free_agents]

        return data
```

#### objects/team.py:

```py
class Team:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.players = []

    def add_player(self, player):
        self.players.append(player)

    def get_players(self):
        return self.players

    def remove_player(self, player):
        self.players.remove(player)

    def get_json(self):
        data = {}

        data['name'] = self.name
        data['players'] = [player.get_json() for player in self.players]

        return data
```

#### objects/player.py:

```py
import uuid

class Player:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, position, rating):
        self.id = uuid.uuid4()
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.position = position
        self.rating = rating
        self.team: str = ''

    def get_full_name(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} {self.last_name}'

    #################################################

    def add_to_team(self, name):
        self.team = name

    def get_team(self):
        return self.team or 'Free Agent'

    def release_from_team(self, name):
        self.team = ''

    #################################################

    def get_json(self):
        data = {}

        data['id'] = str(self.id)
        data['first_name'] = self.first_name
        data['last_name'] = self.last_name
        data['position'] = self.position
        data['rating'] = self.rating
        data['team'] = self.team

        return data
```

#### config/league_config.yaml:

```py
roster-size: 53
team-count: 32
league-player-count: 5000
player-retirement-percentage: 10
player-retirement-percentage-margin-of-error: 5
```

#### resources/play_generator_food.csv *(First 20 lines)*:

```
first_name,last_name
JAMES,SMITH
JOHN,JOHNSON
ROBERT,WILLIAMS
MICHAEL,BROWN
WILLIAM,JONES
DAVID,MILLER
RICHARD,DAVIS
CHARLES,GARCIA
JOSEPH,RODRIGUEZ
THOMAS,WILSON
CHRISTOPHER,MARTINEZ
DANIEL,ANDERSON
PAUL,TAYLOR
MARK,THOMAS
DONALD,HERNANDEZ
GEORGE,MOORE
KENNETH,MARTIN
STEVEN,JACKSON
EDWARD,THOMPSON
...
```

#### resources/team_generator_food.csv *(First 20 lines)*:

```
Alaska
Alabama
Arkansas
Arizona
California
Colorado
Connecticut
Delaware
Florida
Georgia
Hawaii
Iowa
Idaho
Illinois
Indiana
Kansas
Kentucky
Louisiana
Massachusetts
Maryland
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `import utilities.resources as resources` just write `from utilities import resources`.

It's good that you have multiple modules - keep doing that.

Don't represent `league_config` as a dictionary. Represent it as a class instance of some kind. In the ideal case, try to make it immutable. Only convert it to a dictionary for the purposes of serialization.

`verify_league_config` would be a good member function on your new configuration class.

Stop using `os` for path manipulation; use `pathlib` instead.

`except KeyError` is missing a `return False`. It currently only works by accident due to an implicit `return None`.

Add type hints to your function signatures, for example `def verify_league_config() -> bool`.

Use a Python linter to validate your code. Among other things, it will suggest having two newlines between functions for PEP8 compliance.

The `'r'` argument is the default for `open` and can be removed.

The `(0` argument for `range` is the default and can be removed.

Don't `randint(0, team_count-i)`. Instead, `randrange(team_count)`.

`generate_teams` would be better-modelled as an actual generator function that uses `yield` instead of `league.add_team` in a loop.

When iterating over `league_player_count` in `generate_players`, don't iterate over a `range`. Instead, iterate over the rows of the CSV directly, and (assuming that there are only two columns), tuple-unpack them, as in

`for first_name, last_name in csv_contents`

`// 1` is not a good idea. If you want an integer, just cast `int()`.

```
        key = line.split(':')[0]
        value = line.split(':')[1].strip()
```

should be rephrased as

```
key, value = line.strip().split(':', maxsplit=1)
```

When you write prompts of the form

```
'How many teams would you like to start off with?\n$ '
```

there are advantages to instead writing

```
'How many teams would you like to start off with? '
```

This will allow for there to be one line per prompt-response pair.

In an inverted-predicate statement like

```
    if not roster_size.isdigit():
        print('Please insert a number')

    else:
        league_config['roster-size'] = int(roster_size)
        break
```

you're usually better off writing it in positive logic:

```py
if roster_size.isdigit():
    league_config['roster-size'] = int(roster_size)
    break
print('Please insert a number')
```

Don't `min_player_count :=`. Just assign that variable on its own line. The walrus harms legibility in this case.

`build_configuration` should not mutate globals as a side-effect; it should be a side-effect-less function that returns a new configuration object.

Don't `open(os.path.join(get_saves(), f'tmp_{uuid.uuid4()}'), 'w')`. Use [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) instead.

`filters={}` assigns a mutable object as a default function parameter. That can lead to a nasty category of bugs. If `filters` is optional, you're usually better-off doing something like

```py
def print_players(self, filters: dict[str, Any] | None = None) -> None:
    if filters is None:
        filters = {}
```

`print_players` should be separated into at least two functions - one that's a true generator function to perform filtration, and one to actually print.

Don't `player_table +=` iteratively concatenate to a string. Strings are immutable in Python, and this has performance implications. There are several ways around this. One way is to write a generator function that yields lines, where the caller does a `'\n'.join(format_lines())`.

`get_json()` first of all lies about its purpose, since it doesn't make JSON; it makes a dictionary (that could later be serialized to JSON). Also, you should create `data` with a dictionary literal instead of key assignments on separate statements.

Lots more to improve, but that's a start.